# How to use oauth scope with spaces

Tags: soapui, oauth-2.0, ready-api

Currently i've been using Ready!API Soapui NG for my Rest apis. In my client credentials, I have my single string scope like **scope_api** which is able to generate access token. But now I have received new scope for my credentials that contains white spaces. Ex. **scope scope_api1 scope_api2**. In ReadyAPI I got the error `Unable to retrieve token` but when I tried the same scope in POSTMAN, I was able to get an access token. Is there any way to make it work on ReadyAPI? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the screen shot of how you get the `token` in ReadyAPI? or raw request?

Comment: You should do URL encoding before sending the scopes to server.